# Data Extension shows 0 record after successful import via Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio

Background

- We're running an external campaign, using SFTP transfer to import file from external to Marketing Cloud FTP location.
- In Automation Studio, we have an "Import File" action to OVERWRITE a targeted Data Extension.

Problem

- The data transfer is successful.
- The automation is completed.
- However, when I check the targeted data extension, 0 record created.

What I've checked

- The CSV file, everything seems to be correct. Header rows all there and correctly spelled.
- The field mapping in the "Import File" action.
- However, I have the "skip rows with bad data" selected, not sure if this is causing the problem, yet again, I couldn't see anything wrong in the csv file.

I appreciate if anyone can share some tips/diagnosis on the issue!

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Have you tried adding your email to get notification about results in the Import File activity in the Activity Info tab? You would receive an email with all info on the import and the reason why some records were not inserted.

Comment: Every import gets a results file generated if there are any exceptions.  It'll be in your SFTP Import directory.

Comment: Thank you both, really helpful!

Comment: Moved my comment to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It is usually hard to predict why do you have this result without any error text, thus as the first recommendation for troubleshooting - it is better to include your email address in the Activity tab in the Import File activity -

[image]

This way you would receive an email with a short description of the import result and if the number of errored fields is not that big, the file would be directly attached to the email with specifications of what fields had troubles to be imported and with what reason. However, you can always find that .txt file in the Import folder in SFTP, which would contain the External Key of the Import Definition and timestamp in the name. Here is the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320718&type=1) with the majority of existing reasons.

After that, you should be able to adjust your import configuration.